# Java out of memory exception while doing AEM debug in eclipse

Tags: java, out-of-memory, aem, heap-memory

I am using a 64 bit windows machine with 16GB RAM.

I am using AEM and other applications like eclipse. Whenever I run my AEM instance in debug mode and debug through eclipse, I am getting Out of memory exception low heap size. Please find below the screenshot from control panel. I can see no runtime parameters are set for heap size.

[image]

Can someone help on how much I can set here as the heap size compatible with my system specifications.

Adding  a screenshot of my current java heap size

[image]

And this is my debug.bat file

java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=50519 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024m -Dorg.apache.sling.commons.log.level=INFO -jar aem64-author-p4502.jar -p 4502 -verbose -nofork

Comment: What AEM version and Java version are you using?

Comment: Increase the allocated memory: `Xmx2G` at least, 1G for the heap is being insufficient.

Comment: @OliverGebert AEM 6.4